# Understanding pandas groupby().agg() values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I cam across some code for testing Simpson's Paradox, and I'm confused about how it works.

The data is in this form:

[image]

and when I run

```
gb = df_.groupby(["kidney_stone_size", "treatment"]).agg([np.sum, lambda x: len(x)])
gb
```

I get

[image]

I can't  fully understand what `df_.groupby(["kidney_stone_size", "treatment"]).agg([np.sum, lambda x: len(x)])` does.

For one, the aggragate data appears to be calculated from the omitted columns in the `groupby` part, as when I do

`gb = df_.groupby(["recovery", "treatment"]).agg([np.sum, lambda x: len(x)])`

I get

[image]

So is that the default behaviour - that the aggregate data is calculated for the missing columns?

I know you can specify columns explicitly in a dictionary, but I'm trying to understand the code as is.

What exactly is being calculated by the `.agg([np.sum, lambda x: len(x)])`?

i.e what exactly is `np.sum` being applied to, and likewise `lambda x: len(x)`?

Please understand that there may be some conceptual gaps in my understanding that might make what is obvious from the outside non-obvious to me. Any help much appreciated.

Comment: If something still not clear, I try explain more.

Answer (score 1):

> So is that the default behaviour - that the aggregate data is calculated for the missing columns?

I think yes, if not specify column for processing after `groupby` pandas use all columns not used in `groupby` and apply aggregate functions.

> What exactly is being calculated by the .agg([np.sum, lambda x: len(x)])

Here `sum` for non numeric columns working like `join`, for numeric get `sum`, your custom function `lambda x: len(x)` return length of groups - numeric and non numeric.

```
df_ = pd.DataFrame({
        'kidney_stone_size':list('aaaaaa'),
         'recovery':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
         'col1':[1,3,5,7,1,0],
         'col2':['new'] * 6,
         'treatment':list('aaabbb')
})

df = df_.groupby(["kidney_stone_size", "treatment"]).agg([np.sum, lambda x: len(x)])
print (df)
                            recovery            col1                  col2  \
                                 sum <lambda_0>  sum <lambda_0>        sum   
kidney_stone_size treatment                                                  
a                 a               13          3    9          3  newnewnew   
                  b               14          3    8          3  newnewnew   

                                        
                            <lambda_0>  
kidney_stone_size treatment             
a                 a                  3  
                  b                  3
```

But if use only aggregate function working with numeric like `sum`, pandas by default omit non numeric columns:

```
df = df_.groupby(["kidney_stone_size", "treatment"]).sum()
print (df)
                             recovery  col1
kidney_stone_size treatment                
a                 a                13     9
                  b                14     8
```